# Highscores - Best time period for a user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table which keeps track of data from a game, here is an example of the table:

```
id | player_name | date                | score | kills
1  | test1       | 2013-01-01 00:00:00 | 10000 | 200
2  | test1       | 2013-01-01 00:01:00 | 12000 | 300
```

I have a leaderboards for players, it ranks people who gain the most score/kills, etc. in a certain time period. At the moment I have only got it so that it ranks players in the previous 24 hours. I am doing this by selecting the first and last records in a specified time period and then subtracting them to get the difference.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT  date, score FROM datapoints WHERE player_name = :player AND date = (SELECT MIN(date) FROM datapoints WHERE player_name = :player AND date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))
UNION ALL 
SELECT date, score FROM datapoints WHERE player_name = :player AND date =  (SELECT MAX(date) FROM datapoints WHERE player_name = :player AND date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR))
```

After subtracting I use the PHP `arsort()` function to order them and then display them on the page.

However, I want to add another feature. I want to be able to see the on which day was the users best day for score/kills.

I have been thinking of how I could possibly do it and one was was using the above query but having a loop for each day and taking out the best day, however this probably isn't very efficient and I was wondering, if there was a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would get the score changes and kills that occur on any given calendar day:

```
select date(date) as thedate, max(score) - min(score) as DayScore,
       max(kills) - min(kills) as DayKills
from datapoints dp
where player_name = :player
group by date(date);
```

To get the top day for scores, for instance, you would add an `order by` and `limit` clause like this:

```
order by DayScore desc
limit 1;
```